# Access all medias loaded in a web page c#

Tags: c#, selenium, media

i would like to display the URL and type of all the backgrounds, images, and embedded content (including audio and video) that loads with a given web page, exactly like in the media panel page info of firefox :

[image: 1]

Or in firebug network panel > media :

[image: 2]
**How can i achieve this in C#, using selenium ?** (or without, but i don't think it's possible)

Thanks !

Comment: Updated my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Java code is as below :-

```
List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //link[@href]"));
for(WebElement e : myElements) {
  System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```

In C#

```
IList<IWebElement> all = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//link[@href]"));

String[] allText = new String[all.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (IWebElement element in all)
{
    allText[i++] = element.Text;
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This won't do what is asked in the question. He is not looking to execute javascript

Comment: yup .. deleting my answer .. just read it again and get what he asked for

Comment: updated my answer as per OP question :) .. Thanks to let me know

Comment: this won't work, i'm speaking of medias that are not hardcoded in the web page source, but loaded dynamically. I wouldn't use selenium otherwise...

Comment: the same info in media info is showing in HTML link tag